# Set default (current datetime) to table column - CodeIgniter 3 migration

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this migration:

```
public function up(){
    $this->dbforge->add_field([
        'id'=>['type'=>'int', 'unique'=>true, 'unsigned'=>true,'auto_increment'=>true],
        'email'=>['type'=>'varchar', 'constraint'=>200, 'null'=>true],
        'password'=>['type'=>'varchar', 'constraint'=>250],
        'created_at'=>['type'=>'datetime', 'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'],
    ]);
    $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('users', TRUE);
}
```

I am trying to set table with column `created_at` with default value - current datetime.
I am using `'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`, but I am getting this error:

> Invalid default value for 'created_at' ....
>   NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',

I am using `CodeIgniter 3` with `MySQL`.

Comment: instead of `'created_at'=>['type'=>'datetime', 'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP']` try `'created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` -

Comment: Hi, thx it works. It must be placed in the column name key and instead `created_at` will be `created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and remove array (with type, and default) in this key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this worked for me, and is valid in the documentation

> Passing strings as fields If you know exactly how you want a field to
> be created, you can pass the string into the field definitions with
> add_field()
>
> $this->dbforge->add_field("label varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT
> 'default label'");
>
> Note:
> Passing raw strings as fields cannot be followed by add_key() calls on
> those fields.

```
`$this->dbforge->add_field(
  array(
    'name' => 
      array(
        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
        'constraint' => '150',
      ),
    'email' => 
      array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'constraint' => '150',
        'unique'=> TRUE,
    ),
    'username' => 
      array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'constraint' => '80',
    ),
    'created_at datetime default current_timestamp',
    'updated_at datetime default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp',
    'status' => 
      array(
        'type' => 'tinyint',
        'constraint' => '1',
    ),
  )
);`
```

Comment: 'created_at datetime default current_timestamp', this is not working in PostgreSQL

Comment: is raw sql, it seems to me that the syntax for postgresql is
created_at timestamp DEFAULT NOW()

Answer (score 2):

For Codeigniter 4 this is slightly different:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/dbmgmt/forge.html#raw-sql-strings-as-default-values

You would need something like this ...

```
'DateAdded'     => array(
    'type'      => 'TIMESTAMP',
    'default'   => new RawSql('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
),
```